# In Q-learning with function approximation, is it possible to avoid hand-crafting features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, q-learning, function-approximation

I have little background knowledge of Machine Learning, so please forgive me if my question seems silly.

Based on what I've read, the best model-free reinforcement learning algorithm to this date is Q-Learning, where each state,action pair in the agent's world is given a q-value, and at each state the action with the highest q-value is chosen. The q-value is then updated as follows:

Q(s,a) = (1-α)Q(s,a) + α(R(s,a,s') + (max_a' * Q(s',a'))) where α is the learning rate.

Apparently, for problems with high dimensionality, the number of states become astronomically large making q-value table storage infeasible.

So the practical implementation of Q-Learning requires using Q-value approximation via generalization of states aka features. For example if the agent was Pacman then the features would be:

- Distance to closest dot
- Distance to closest ghost
- Is Pacman in a tunnel?

And then instead of q-values for every single state you would only need to only have q-values for every single feature.

So my question is:

**Is it possible for a reinforcement learning agent to create or generate additional features?**

Some research I've done:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26601252/800735) mentions A Geramifard's iFDD method

- http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/473_icmlpaper.pdf
- http://people.csail.mit.edu/agf/Files/13RLDM-GQ-iFDD+.pdf

which is a way of "discovering feature dependencies", but I'm not sure if that is feature generation, as the paper assumes that you start off with a set of binary features.

Another paper that I found was apropos is [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602v1.pdf), which "extracts high level features using a range of neural network architectures".

I've read over the paper but still need to flesh out/fully understand their algorithm. Is this what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you already answered your own question :)

Feature generation is not part of the Q-learning (and SARSA) algorithm. In a process which is called preprocessing you can however use a wide array of algorithms (of which you showed some) to generate/extract features from your data. Combining different machine learning algorithms results in *hybrid* architectures, which is a term you might look into when researching what works best for your problem.

Here is an [example of using features with SARSA](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_272.html) (which is very similar to Q-learning).
Whether the papers you cited are helpful for your scenario, you'll have to decide for yourself. As always with machine learning, *your approach is highly problem-dependent*. If you're in robotics and it's hard to define discrete states manually, a neural network might be helpful. If you can think of heuristics by yourself (like in the pacman example) then you probably won't need it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know any articles that describe how one might generate heuristics using a neural network? Or perhaps popular/generally accepted methods of feature generation? I've done searches on convolutional networks, multilayer perceptrons, restricted Boltzmann machines and recurrent neural networks - but they seem to be very broad topics. I'm currently learning about the backpropagation/feed-forward algorithm used in neural networks, but am having trouble thinking about how to apply them for feature generation.